# How can I repackage a vagrant box to end up with a larger partition?

Tags: centos, vagrant, virtualbox, centos7

I'd like to use https://app.vagrantup.com/centos/boxes/7 in such a way as I end up with a VM with a 100GB primary partition.

While other questions address how to set the disk size for the VM, following those instructions still results in a 40GB partition being created when using this box. Other questions also address how to resize the partitions from within the guest OS after the fact.

What steps (even if general) would be necessary to have a version of the above box that results in a larger formatted partition?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

First install this plugin and then repackage your vagrant box

https://github.com/sprotheroe/vagrant-disksize

Read also the "limitations" on this page!